# How to use ruby uniq on nested array/hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, hash

I am trying to call the uniq method on the follow json so that it would only return unique result base on employee_id

```
# Json array
a ={
  results: [
   {
    employee: {
      name: "A",
      employee_id: "A-00016",
      title: 1
     }
   },{
    employee: {
      name: "A",
      employee_id: "A-00016",
      title: 2
     }
   },{
    employee: {
      name: "C",
      employee_id: "C-00017",
      title: 3
     }
    }
   ]
  }



# Calling uniq on a
a.uniq { |p| p.values_at(:employee_id) }
```

However, I am only getting this result

```
{
  results: [
   {
    employee: {
      name: "A",
      employee_id: "A-00016",
      title: 1
     }
    }
   ]
  }
```

Instead of what I want

```
{
  results: [
   {
    employee: {
      name: "A",
      employee_id: "A-00016",
      title: 1
     },{
    employee: {
      name: "C",
      employee_id: "C-00017",
      title: 3
     }
    }
   ]
  }
```

Am I using the correct method to output the result I want?

Comment: I would recommend to do : `a[:results].uniq!` but you have title=1 in the first instance and title=2 in the second. So, ruby will consider the two first  as different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, in order to return the modified input `hash`, we can use `uniq!` which will modify the array `a[:results]` in place. We use `dup` to duplicate the hash `a` to preserve it, and then use `tap` to operate on duplicated hash.

```
r = a.dup.tap do |h|
  h[:results].uniq! do |h|
    h[:employee][:employee_id]
  end
end

#=> {:results=>
#    [
#     {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>1}},
#     {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}
#    ]
#   }
```

Comment: Thank you! The method works but I voted @mudasobwa answer because it uses uniq.

Comment: @TomCheung  Other answer does not produce the desired output.  This solution uses `uniq!` to get the desired output

Answer (score 3):

With `uniq`:

```
input[:results].uniq { |e| e[:employee][:employee_id] }
#⇒ [
#    {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>"1"}},
#    {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>"3"}}]
```

But I believe there should be some condition applied on what to choose from siblings having the same `id`. The code below selects the one, having max `title` value:

```
input[:results].group_by { |e| e[:employee][:employee_id] }
               .map { |_, v| v.max_by { |e| e[:employee][:title].to_i } }
#⇒ [
#    {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>"2"}},
#    {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>"3"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def selection_criterion(h)
  h[:title].to_i
end

{results: a[:results].group_by {|h| h[:employee][:employee_id]}.
                      values.
                      map {|arr| arr.max_by {|h|  selection_criterion(h[:employee])}}}
   #=> {:results=>
   #     [{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}},
   #      {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}]}
```

Define `selection_criterion` as desired, and possible change `max_by` to `min_by`.

The steps are as follows.

```
 b = a[:results]
   # => [{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>1}},
   #     {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}},
   #     {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}] 
 c = b.group_by { |h| h[:employee][:employee_id] }
   #=> {"A-00016"=>[{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>1}},
   #                {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}}],
   #    "C-00017"=>[{:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}]}
 d = c.values
   #=> [[{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>1}},
   #     {:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}}],
   #    [{:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}]] 
 e = d.map { |arr| arr.max_by { |h| selection_criterion(h[:employee]) } }
   #=> [{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}},
   #    {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}]
 { results: e }
   #=> {:results=>
   #     [{:employee=>{:name=>"A", :employee_id=>"A-00016", :title=>2}},
   #      {:employee=>{:name=>"C", :employee_id=>"C-00017", :title=>3}}]}
```